# Find a basis for the kernel and the image of this transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\\\c&d\end{bmatrix} \longrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}a\\\\a\\\\3a+b\end{bmatrix}$$

As the kernel maps everything to zero then $a=0$ and $3a+b=0$ so the basis is of the form

$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\\\1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$$

However i'm not sure if this is correct so far

Comment: Looks good.  Have you tried to find the image yet?

Comment: Do you mean $3a + b = 0$? (it doesn't change the solution, of course).

Comment: @ChristopherA.Wong yes I have changed it now

Comment: @icurays1 No I'm not sure where to start for the image

Answer (score 1):

To find the image of this transformation, I would first break up my image vector into a sum:

$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}
a\\a\\3a+b
\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{c}
a\\a\\3a
\end{array}\right]+
\left[\begin{array}{c}
0\\0\\b
\end{array}\right]=a\left[\begin{array}{c}
1\\1\\3
\end{array}\right]+
b\left[\begin{array}{c}
0\\0\\1
\end{array}\right]
$$

You should be able to take it from there (hint: what do you need to show to prove something is a basis?)

Comment: so from here I just need to show they are linearly independant and span

Comment: Yep, you've got it!